# How to set up correctly cdk drag-drop for Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

see my steps

1. > npm install @angular/cdk
2. in app.module.ts  -> import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop'; and import: [DragDropModule]
3. next I want create drag and drops cards list. I created component for one card, and created parrent component when I will to get [{data}], produce card and pass current data for current card.

Parrent component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-groups',
  templateUrl: './groups.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./groups.component.scss']
})
export class GroupsComponent implements OnInit {

  groups = [something data]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.groups, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Parrent component HTML

```
<div cdkDropList class="groups" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let group of groups">
        <app-group cdkDrag [data]="group"></app-group>
    </div>

</div>
```

But drag and drop on my card doesn't work, please help me)

i have warning (event cdkdroplistdropped is not emitted by any applicable directives nor by div element) for (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event) in component HTML

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. This code is work!

```
<div class="groups" >
    <div cdkDropList class="groups__wrapper" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let group of groups">
            <app-group cdkDrag cdkDragHandle [data]="group"></app-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your **?.component.html** code by this:

```
    <div cdkDropList class="groups" [cdkDropListData]="groups (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let group of groups" cdkDrag>
            {{ group }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tested in an application and it runs ok.